# Is it possible to access a lightning community custom theme's 'Theme Settings' in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I have built a custom theme for a customer. This custom theme has several 'Theme Settings' defined in the  file.

Depending on what has been selected in the 'Theme Settings' several custom lightning components need to change. These lightning components are added via 'drag and drop' in the community builder so are not specifically part of the custom theme.

The reason for this is so that my customer does not have to change 10+ component settings, they only have to set one and the setting is distributed down the hierarchy.

Is it possible that I can access these 'Theme Settings' in components that have been dragged and dropped into the community builder? It's not the end of the world if I can't, but it would make my customer's life easier.

So, for example, I have a custom theme design file such as:

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="SomeBoolean" label="Some boolean that is needed in child components."/>
</design:component>
```

I then have a component that I drag into the community builder and that could morph depending on this setting:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.customtheme.SomeBoolean == true}">
        something something something
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

As a side note, I **am not** asking how to pass attributes from a parent to child. I **am** asking how to consume 'Theme Settings' in components dragged into the community builder.